# Publishing to bintray with kotlin dsl script

Tags: kotlin

I have been trying to publish my kotlin library and I was following the instructions given at https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin/blob/master/README.md . Fortunately I was able to migrate the most part of it to kotlin. But I can't seem to fix the error it gives for the `pkg` part. It says

> Type mismatch: inferred type is () -> TypeVariable(_L) but
>   Closure<(raw) Any!>! was expected.

I just can't seem to fix this part, any examples as to how to implement this in kotlin would be great.

Comment: Could you add code snippet with what you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`delegateClosureOf<...>`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#groovy_closures_from_kotlin) for closures in the bintray configurations:

```
bintray {
    ...
    pkg(delegateClosureOf<BintrayExtension.PackageConfig> {
        repo = "maven"
        ...
        version(delegateClosureOf<BintrayExtension.VersionConfig> {
            ...
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using closure syntax, you can use `.apply`:

```
bintray {
    ...
    pkg = PackageConfig().apply {
        repo = ""
        ...
        version = VersionConfig().apply {
            name = ""
            ...
        }
    }
}
```